# Angularjs, accessing rootScope or service from a nested directive

Tags: sorting, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a sorting directive in the th cells of a list directive.

I am trying to sort the resource that is being used to populate the list when you click on the header of the cell, I want the sort to happen at the database level, so I'm trying to send a call to the service from a function in the rootScope.

From the sorting directive I get an error whenever I try to access the sorting function at the rootScope level.  Alternatively, can I make service calls to the passed resource from the list directive?

here's the plunkr I'm working with:  http://plnkr.co/edit/SiBDuylEv1LUCuWCv5Ep?p=preview

right now it's calling static data and I'm using the orderBy filter to sort the data.

the problem is that I want the user to be able to key through the list using arrow keys. The orderBy filter just rearranges the repeated items, it doesn't reorder the array, which is screwing up the keyboard function.

Answer (score 4):

Right now you have a typo, you're calling `orderby` rather than `orderBy` triggering an error ("Unknown provider: orderbyFilterProvider <- orderbyFilter")

Changing line 7 of directivelist.html to this gets rid of the error.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in set | orderBy:sortBy:reverse" ng-class="getClass(item)" ng-click="selectItem(item,$event,$index)" ng-dblclick="details(item)">
```

Comment: Maybe I forgot to save the plunkr.  I got that part fixed last night.  Thanks, though!

Comment: I made the same mistake, Thanks